# How do you solve recurrent polynomial relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I managed to solve simple linear recursive relations with the help of **generating functions**, but I have trouble applying it to polynomial recurrent relations like this:

$$a_nx_n^2 - (2\sqrt{x_{n+1}} + a_nx_{n+1})x_n + x_{n+1}^{3/2}= 0$$

Where $x \ge 1 $.

Comment: The square roots make this not polynomial.

Comment: @RossMillikan What would be the correct name?

Comment: I don't know of one.  marty cohen has shown how to make it polynomial, but I don't see a reasonable way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

By setting
$x_n=y_n^2$,

$a_nx_n^2 - (2\sqrt{x_{n+1}} + a_nx_{n+1})x_n + x_{n+1}^{3/2}= 0
$
becomes
$a_ny_n^4 - (2y_{n+1} + a_ny^2_{n+1})y^2_n + y_{n+1}^{3}= 0
$
which is polynomial but definitely not linear.

Note that $y_{n+1}$
is a quadratic in $y_n$
so it can explicitly be represented in terms of
$y_n$ using the quadratic formula.